# Is there a way to keep Spring default login page while disabling CSRF?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security

I'm working on a site developed with Spring+Angular and the default login page just worked fine for me.

The problem was that I needed to disable CRLF validation in order to send POST requests from my Angular site so I disabled it.

Now the default login page is not showing so I no longer have authorization verification.

Is there any way of keeping both?

I have tried commenting the line of code which disables it and it seems the login disappears at the moment I add a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        //http.cors().and().csrf().disable(); //Still doesn't work
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add annotation @Configuration to this class. It's help spring know your config security.

Comment: ```@EnableWebSecurity``` already adds ```@Configuration``` by itself.

Comment: '@Configuration'
'@EnableWebSecurity'
'@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)'
There are annotations i added in my class. Mode cors i configured in filter request, in class security i'm only adding http.csrf().disable();. I think it's the way to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself adding a few things to HttpSecurity

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic(); //This fixed it
}
```